# What is the best way to debug substrate?

Tags: debugging

I'm currently studying/debugging the `Treasury` and the `Society` pallets. So I keep running the `cargo build --release` to get my changes on a new binary.

But the build takes too long (minutes) just to reflect an addition/removal of a `log::info!("...")` line.

Is there a better (quicker) way to debug the `runtime`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question!

You can always use the [Substrate Playground](https://docs.substrate.io/playground/).

As far as builds, I typically work off of the [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) repo which is "lighter" than the full [substrate](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate) repo (which includes all the pallets) when it comes to building the whole codebase.

For development purposes I will run `cargo build` without the `--release` flag which according to rust will skip optimizations and therefore should be faster. `cargo check` is even faster but does not produce the final binary.

If I am debugging a specific pallet, I will only compile that pallet (without the release flag): `cargo build -p super-pallet` instead of compiling the entire node. You can also run `cargo check -p super-pallet` which should be even faster.

As a side note, for code-related debugging I recommend  the [rust analyzer extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=matklad.rust-analyzer) in [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) in combination with [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) which is useful for debugging Substrate code.

And there are also helpful Substrate debugging tips here:

- https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/debugging

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, @bruno! I would only add the option to run `cargo test -p super-pallet` for a specific pallet in order to quick check its code.